# Parsing large XML file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js

So I have an XML file that is larger than 70mb. I would like to parse this data for in Node.js to do data visualizations on it eventually. To start, I thought it would be best to use JSON instead of XML, because Node.js is better built to work with JSON. So I planned to use the xml2json node module to parse the xml into JSON but I can't seem to write the xml file to a variable because its so large. I attempted to do this with the following code.

```
var fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile(__dirname + '/xml/ipg140114.xml', 'utf8', function(err, data, parseXml) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    } 
});
```

I receive a stack trace error. **Whats a better way to get this file converted into JSON so I can parse it with Node?** I am pretty new to Node so let me know if my approach is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Example to convert Xml to JSON for large Xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845922/node-js-example-to-convert-xml-to-json-for-large-xml-file)

Answer (score 0):

`Json2xml` requires you to load the entire file into memory. You could allocate more memory but I would recommend parsing the XML directly from the file instead.

There are other libraries on NPM such as `xml-stream` that will allow you to parse the XML directly form the file without loading it all into memory.

My personal issue with `xml-stream` is that it relies on `GYP`, which can be a hassle if you're a windows user.
I added a very basic parser called `no-gyp-xml-stream` to NPM, this one only depends on sax. But it's a bit rudimentary and may not suit your needs.
I am however willing to improve it if anyone needs anything:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-gyp-xml-stream